# How to customize logout options under Kubuntu

Tags: kde, grub2, reboot, kubuntu

I'm running a machine with Kubuntu and Windows XP in dual-boot.

I recently learned about the very useful `grub-reboot` command, and id like to know if it is possible to customize the logout options (like seen on Kickoff last tab, on the dialog that appears when pressing the PC power button, and so on) in order to integrate a "Reboot as Windows" option.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://askubuntu.com/a/63079/101774

Comment: More or less, it explains how to create a launcher (which, more or less was as I had conceived it) but not how to integrate it in the system menu.

Answer (score 0):

if you use kdm you can get a drop down after you click [reboot|shutdown]!

I don't know if this option actaly calls `grub(2)-set-default` (do until you select an other option) or `grub(2)-reboot` (once)

you should make sure you have the following entry in `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
```

and if you want to save the entry after it is selected in grub use:

```
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

afer this run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

then in kde go to:

K-menu => Settings => System Settings => Login Screen( under System Administration)

go to the Shutdown tab and there set your boot manager to Grub2

you will have to restart kdm to make this effective with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/kdm restart
```